# MySQL converting number to string automatically (Error)

Tags: mysql, string, casting, numbers, mode

I have been experiencing a problem with one of my tables. **Sometimes**, when entering a number in column *`value`*, it is being converted to `''`, **0** or strange symbols like `Ð©¬M`.

Here is its structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `table_name` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `key` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `value` TEXT NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE KEY `id_2` (`id`, `key`),
    KEY `id` (`ìd`), 
    CONSTRAINT `table_name_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `table2` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

I do not know, but I had a malfunction in one of the systems that used another table of same database and I had to set SQL mode to `''` through `SET GLOBAL sql_mode = '';` to make it work. I want to know if this mode is leading to the reported problem. I read about change SQL mode and realized this could cause data loss, something that I cannot think about at the moment.

So, if this is the real cause of the problem, is there a possible solution without data loss? And if this is not the problem, could someone help me to identify what it is?

PS: The data type of the column *`value`* must be **TEXT** due to other necessary information.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you face problem while using INSERT QUERY through code, if so did you tried doing INSERT QUERY operation using PHPMYADMIN or any available sql query client?

Comment: @PrasadWargad Hi, Prasad. This problem occurs both ways. Is there chance of a problem related to sql mode?